# XML Parsing => "What is wrong in this code"

Tags: android, xml

When I'm trying to run my program application crashes,what i have done wrong i cant understand,I have no idea what to do, Please help me out.

Here is my code that i have done so far,

MainActivity.java

```java
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://www.androidpeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/example.xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
//static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
static final String KEY_WEBSITE_CATEGORY = "website";
//static final String KEY_DESC = "description";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
    // looping through all item nodes <item>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        //map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
        map.put(KEY_WEBSITE_CATEGORY, "Rs." + parser.getValue(e,KEY_WEBSITE_CATEGORY));
        //map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        menuItems.add(map);
    }
}
}
```

XMLParser.java

```java
public class XMLParser {

// constructor
public XMLParser() {

}

/**
 * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
 * @param url string
 * */
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}

/**
 * Getting XML DOM element
 * @param XML string
 * */
public Document getDomElement(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
        doc = db.parse(is);

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

    return doc;
}

public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
    Node child;
    if( elem != null){
        if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
            for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                    return child.getNodeValue();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}

public String getValue(Element item, String str) {
    NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
    return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
}
```

}

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.jszala.xmldemo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.jszala.xmldemo.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

LogCat Error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jszala.xmldemo/com.jszala.xmldemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

Comment: Update question title with proper question. And don't use caps for next time.

Comment: You are doing Http request from main thread, use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: shows your xml. post the same here

Comment: @JaydipsinhZala I know why you are here. But you should ask your question into correct format.

Comment: @PankajKumar i will take care of it next time for sure thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the docs

`ListActivity` has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen. **However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Make sure you have the below for listiew

```
 android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Also you have this `String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL)`. You are probably running network related operation on the ui thread. So if you are getting xml from server use a `thread` or `Asynctask`

You need to have this  `HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost)` inside a `thread` or `Asynctask` .

Edit:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @JaydipsinhZala you need to have this `android:id="@android:id/list"` for your listview in `activity_main.xml`.

Comment: ya, i have already given the id as you are saying.

Comment: @JaydipsinhZala post your `activity_main.xml`. if you have you will not get that exception or error.

Comment: I have posted it plz see.

Comment: Still getting same Logcat Error..

Comment: You should not if you do it right. where do you initialize your listview in your activity. Do you populate the listview with data?

Comment: I have not Initialized my listview yet, because of application get crashes.

Comment: @JaydipsinhZala try the edit as a new project. it should not crash. I guess you can try uninstall and re-install also.

Comment: I have Initialized my ListView but result is still same.

Comment: @JaydipsinhZala i am sorry off the top of my head. the above edit works for me. I can't help further coz the code looks fine to me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38786/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-jaydipsinh-zala)

Comment: @JaydipsinhZala why did you unaccept now?